# How to send a json response to broswe using passport

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, authentication, passport.js

Hi I'm trying to do local login using passport.Everything works well however i want to be able to display the username once the user is authenticated here's my code using Node.js and mysql:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        var status = [];
        console.log('-----');

        connection.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE email ="' + email + '"', function(err, rows) {

            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (rows.length) {
                status.push({
                    username: rows[0].username
                });
                done(null, JSON.stringify(status)); //output as JSON

                //console.log(JSON.stringify(status)); 


                //res.render ('"status":'+JSON.stringify(status));
            }
        });

    }
));

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
    failureRedirect: '/loginFailure',
    failureFlash: false
}));

app.get('/loginFailure', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Failed to authenticate');
});

app.get('/loginSuccess', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Successfully authenticated');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your authentication is working properly, the user data used by Passport is stored in the req.user variable on every request. Passing the req.user variable to your views will give you the user information.

Also look at the serializeUser() and deserializeUser() functions used by passport. You don't show them in your code, but they are required by passport in order for sessions to work. Basically, your LocalStrategy authenticates the user, the serializeUser() function prepares the session data, and the deserializeUser() function reads the session data and creates the req.user variable.